# How we can customized Assets Admin Search Rail search form in AEM

Tags: adobe, aem, livefyre

How we can edit/update Assets Admin Search Rail search form in AEM if it is lock by default. Tried to edit it and want to save the changes but it shows me an error "Search facets could not be customized."

Comment: Any help here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working in 6.1 by doing overlay of /libs/dam/gui/content/facets
(copy folder: /libs/dam/gui/content/facets to /apps/dam/gui/content/facets using crxde).

This removes the lock sign in front of the "Assets Admin Search Rail". After this edit works.

Reference link: https://shreshthkumar.wordpress.com/

---

Also,
In AEM 6.2, it works out of the box, without doing overlay. It saves the facets changes at: /conf/global/settings/dam/search/facets/assets/jcr:content/items/